# anyone knowing progress of asp.net mvc 4

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there anyone got a knowledge about asp.net mvc 4 roadmap and new features (not wishlist)? And will it be based on .net 4 or 5 ?

**EDIT**
released  http://haacked.com/archive/2011/07/13/asp-net-mvc-4-roadmap.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Roadmap for ASP.NET MVC 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227987/roadmap-for-asp-net-mvc-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MVC 3 roadmap was on the codeplex site, [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC&referringTitle=Home). Its not been updated with MVC 4 roadmap but I'd recommend checking this out regularly to see if it does get updated. Also checkout Phil Haack's blog, [here](http://haacked.com/) as he sometimes talks about up coming features.

As for .Net version I'm guessing it will still be compatible with .Net 4 even if version 5 is out by then (much like they did with MVC 2) but that is just my guess.

---

Update

A high level roadmap for version 4 has just been release, [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%204%20RoadMap).